# nested structures with pointer in C

Tags: c, struct, nested

i want to use nested structures with pointers in c. i write this code but i dont know why this code not working. actually how can i allocate memory for my second structure?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct address
{
    int code;
    char city[10];
};
struct student {
    char name[10];
    struct address *ads;
} *person1;

int main()
{

person1 = malloc(sizeof(struct student));
scanf("%s", person1->name);
scanf("%d", &person1->ads->code);
scanf("%s", person1->ads->city);

printf("%s", person1->name);
printf("%d", person1->ads->code);
printf("%s", person1->ads->city);
return 0;
}
```

NOTE: when i use "person1->ads = malloc(sizeof(struct address));" program ran to problem and stop working.

---

[Update from comment:]

I use DEV C++ v5.4.2

Comment: You have not allocated memory for the ads member. So you need to add something like person1->ads = malloc(sizeof(struct address));

Comment: i guess and test.. but program ran to problem

Comment: For this layout, I wouldn't make `ads` a pointer in the first place. Just declare it in `struct student` as `struct address ads;` and populate it with `person1->ads.` .

Comment: @WhozCraig you are right; but i want to test this way for myself.

Comment: @AmirMohammadNasrollahi The answers below are correct. You're not doing something right, and its too early/late for my code-clairvoyance to stab guesses. Amend your question with the attempt you *currently* have that incorporates *either* answer below. Don't *replace* your posted code; update the question with an EDIT content that shows *exactly* what you have now and how you're running it.

Comment: @WhozCraig i know that many of below answers are correct but in this situation just answer of iharob works for me and also he mention to my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few poblems

1. You don't check the success of `malloc`.
2. You don't `malloc` for `person1->ads` member.
3. You don't check the success of `scanf`.

This is a fixed and anotated version of your code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct address
{
    int code;
    char city[10];
};

struct student
{
    char name[10];
    struct address *ads;
};

int main()
{
    /* You don't need te struct to be global, and it's generally a bad idea, not always of course */
    struct student *person;

    /* you should check that malloc succeeded otherwise undefined behavior would happen */
    person = malloc(sizeof(*person));
    if (person == NULL)
    {
        printf("cannot allocate memory\n");
        return -1;
    }

    /* you should check that scanf succeeded too */
    if (scanf("%9s", person->name) != 1)
    /*          ^ prevent buffer overflow */
    {
        printf("Invalid, input\n");
        free(person);
        return -1;
    }

    person->ads = malloc(sizeof(*(person->ads)));
    if (person->ads == NULL)
    {
        printf("cannot allocate memory\n");
        /* on failure free successfuly allocated person */
        free(person);
        return -1;
    }

    /* you should check that scanf succeeded too */
    if (scanf("%d", &person->ads->code) != 1)
    {
        printf("Invalid, input\n");

        free(person->ads);
        free(person);

        return -1;
    }

    /* you should check that scanf succeeded too */
    if (scanf("%9s", person->ads->city) != 1)
    /*          ^ prevent buffer overflow */
    {
        printf("Invalid, input\n");

        free(person->ads);
        free(person);

        return -1;
    }

    printf("Name: %s\n", person->name);
    printf("Code: %d\n", person->ads->code);
    printf("City: %s\n", person->ads->city);

    free(person->ads);
    free(person);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1+ for scaning with limits ... :-)

Comment: @AmirMohammadNasrollahi عفوًا

Comment: @iharob my language is Persian not ARABIC! i think you try to say 'خواهش میکنم' :)))

Comment: @alk there are more elegant ways of handling that, but just for ilustrative purposes I think it's ok.

Comment: Yes, sure. Just as I was used to ... ;-) @iharob

Comment: What if `ads` is an array of elements ? how to index it as a pointer and not as an array ?

Comment: There's no fundamental difference. To index it as a pointer you MUST compute the offset in bytes. Whereas if you access it using the `[]` operator you can do it by specifying the "array" index. In both cases the same offset is added to the base address. But in the first case you have to say how many bytes and in the second case you don't.

Answer (score 4):

You need to also allocate memory for members stored via pointer.

```
int main()
{  
    person1 = malloc(sizeof(struct student));
    person1->ads = malloc(sizeof(struct address));
    scanf("%s", person1->name);
    scanf("%d", &person1->ads->code);
    scanf("%s", person1->ads->city);

    printf("%s", person1->name);
    printf("%d", person1->ads->code);
    printf("%s", person1->ads->city);
    free(person1->ads);
    free(person1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @AmirMohammadNasrollahi , Change `int name[10];` to `char name[10];` and it will work.

Comment: @CoolGuy ohhh sorry!! a mistake from me! :)

Comment: @CoolGuy but this not the main issue of this problem. my problem is about allocating memory and still not working...

Comment: @amir-mohammad-nasrollahi what exactly is not working? Please be more precise.

Comment: @AmirMohammadNasrollahi , I tested the code in TomaszKlak's answer and also changed what I've said in my previous comment and it worked. Try checking the return value of `malloc` to see if it failed.

Comment: @TomaszKłak when i press F5 then program appear for 1 second and immediately program stop working. actually it happen at first of my compile.

Answer (score 3):

> how can i allocate memory for my second structure?

For example the same way as you did for the first structure: allocate it from the heap

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct address
{
  int code;
  char city[10];
};

struct student 
{
  char name[10];
  struct address * ads;
};

int main(void)
{
  struct student * person1 = malloc(sizeof * person1);
  if (NULL == person1)
  {
    perror("malloc() failed for person1");
  }
  else
  {
    person1->ads = malloc(sizeof * person1->ads);
    if (NULL == person1->ads)
    {
      perror("malloc() failed for person1->ads");
    }
    else
    {
      /* scan and print */

      free(person1->ads);
    } 

    free(person1);
  }
}
```

Comment: okey i know!! but how? i test many ways and all of them not working! :D

Comment: good way and i understand it but still have problem with identifying "person1->ads" and stop working. i dont know why really your code not working in this compiler.

Comment: @AmirMohammadNasrollahi: Does it work if you comment out the scaning/printing code?

Comment: @AmirMohammadNasrollahi ,"...this compiler" Which compiler?

Comment: this version of C compiler which i use. i use DEV C++ v5.4.2

Comment: DEV C++ doesn't sound like a C compiler. @AmirMohammadNasrollahi